# php constants math operation

Tags: php, constants

Currently i am learning php. Here I have a confusion this is my php code

```
class OBJECT_ENUM
{
    const USER = 10;
    const POST = 30;
    const SECURE_REQUEST = 40;
}

class OPERATION_ENUM
{
    const INSERT_USER = OBJECT_ENUM::USER + 1; // <- here it gives an error
    const SEND_MAIL = OBJECT_ENUM::USER + 2;

    const LIKE_POST = OBJECT_ENUM::POST + 1;
    const INSERT_POST = OBJECT_ENUM::POST + 2;

    const ENCRYPT = OBJECT_ENUM::SECURE_REQUEST + 1;
}

error message: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/workspace/6thAssignment/include/tempCall.php on line 15
```

I just don't understand why this error occurs.?? cany anybody explain me.??

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the relation between two classes? They aren't in a relation in that code.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: relation is only that i want to use the value of OBJECT_ENUM constant into OPERATION_ENUM class there is no other relations I have a file 'tempCall.php' and both are placed as it is within a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

As you can see in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php:

> The value must be a constant expression, **not** (for example) a
>   variable, a property, **a result of a mathematical operation**, or a
>   function call.

**UPDATED:**

From PHP version 5.6 [now it is possible to use expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) in constants.

Comment: Quite important to realized about your update. It's POSSIBLE to do operations from PHP 5.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not do mathematical operation to be assigned to a const variable. Try changing

```
const INSERT_USER = OBJECT_ENUM::USER + 1;
```

to

```
$INSERT_USER = OBJECT_ENUM::USER + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe expressions (like $a + 1) are not allowed in constants definitions, so there is why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not allowed by PHP. There was an RFC (Request for comments) to get this added to the language:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_expressions

however this was withdrawn as the author of the RFC has left the internals development team. So I suspect this may not happen any time soon but that's not to say that this won't come back in some form or another at a later date.